# Disable a validation control in Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have asp.net web form with lot of .net controls. where few of the controls are disabled depending on the input of another controls. All of the controls are required so i have to check for required validation as well.
I can disable the control using jquery but i am not able to disable the validation control.

Here is my code.. any better way of doing this will be very appreciable.

```
  <script>

       $('#<%=rdb_one.ClientID%> input:radio').click(function () {

     var currentIdone = 'Humans';
     var currentId = $(this).val();
     if (currentId != currentIdone) {
         $('#<%=rdb_two.ClientID%> input').attr('checked', false);
         $('#<%=rdb_two.ClientID%> input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');


     }
     else {

         $('#<%=lstExposureValue.ClientID%> input').removeAttr('disabled');



     }

 });

 </script>

 <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="Required"  ID="rdb_one" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdb_studysubj_SelectedIndexChanged">
          <asp:ListItem Value="Humans">Humans</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="Non-Human primates">Non-Human primates</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="Rodents">Rodents</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Value="Others">Others</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:RadioButtonList>
      <br/>
      <br/>
         <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="Required" ID="rdb_two" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdb_study_popul_SelectedIndexChanged">
           <asp:ListItem>Individuals</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>Population</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:RadioButtonList>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vald_one" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Study Population is Required" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rdb_two"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Here i disable the control **"rdb_two"** depending on the value from **"rdb_one"** but i am not able to disable the validation controls for **"rdb_two"** any ideas. i have this function repeatedly used over all the controls with in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValidatorEnable function
for example

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')), false);
```

Comment: i dont see that function in jquery..is it a plugin or something

Comment: its a javascript function ,which enables or disables a client validator.

Comment: you may refer this post http://forums.asp.net/t/1175267.aspx?ValidatorEnable+Javascript+Function

Comment: i tried this  ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById($('#<%=rdb_two.ClientID%>').attr('id')), false);  but i get script error  object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: you need to provide validator id to ValidatorEnable function  and your validator id is vald_one not rdb_two